# Java: How to change mongodb port configured with spring boot yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

With java I can do the following to change the tomcat port:

```
java -jar spring-5.jar --server.port=8083
```

That works for changing the default 8080 port in my yml file but what if I also want to change the default mongo db port:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: test
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
```

can I do:

```
java -jar spring-5.jar --mongodb.port=27018
```

Will the above work? I could not find any docs on how to change the mongodb port in a spring boot project once compiled into a JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this,

```
--spring.data.mongodb.port=27018
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
java -jar spring-5.jar --spring.data.mongodb.port=27018
```

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways to overwrite the configure in the jar package. Here are some common ways, try one of them:

1. `application.properties` on your work directory.
2. OS environment variables like SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27018
3. Java System properties like `java -Dspring.data.mongodb.port=27018 -jar the.jar`
4. Spring Boot's command line arguments like `jar -jar the.jar --spring.data.mongodb.port=27018`. Don't forget to pass the `args` from `main()` to `SpringApplication.run`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html for more information